# How to make textarea move from top-left

Tags: html, css

My textarea is staying at the top left. I am trying to get it to display in the center of the display. Here is my html/css:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDAZWJBDC63Y

Comment: Please don't include external links next time, when you can also input your `html/js/css` here as well, enjoy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick if you want it to be center vertically.

```
.fill {    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If you want it to be horizontally centered as well, add `justify-content` center like this.

```
.fill {    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
.body {
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/dQtH57ix3NWDKOQeQM/giphy.gif);
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #00000d;
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: .8;
  /* added these three fields */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.proxies {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5276b58f35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="everything">
  <right class="body">
    <div class="fill">
      <textarea name="proxies" id="proxies" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
  </right>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

so I would recommend you to look into flex which makes aligning item in the DOM more easily. Anyway that aside to answer your question you can just add the following code to you .fill class and it will center it horizontal and vertical.

```
.fill{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center; //To center it vertically
     justify-content: center; //To center it horizontal
    }
```